# CentOS + Huawei 171

Tags: centos, сеть

Было дело, однажды воткнул модем Huawei 171 с симкой Мегафон в *Debian 8 KDE* и дебиан сам его опознал, сделал подключение, у меня попросил только APN проверить, все работало, инет был. Сейчас надо настроить его на CentOS, в дистрибутиве - *FreePBX 12.0.76.2  'VoIP Server'*.

Посмотрел видит ли система устройство командой lsusb - видит и опзонает модель, далее командой **ifconfig -a** смотрю подключения и вижу только *eth0* и *lo*, ничего напоминающего *wlan0* нет, NetworkManager запущен, хотелось бы узнать как вообще поднять модем через консоль если система его не видит как модем.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в ручную прописать в /etc/network/interfaces свой wlan0. Один раз так делал (только помоему на Kali) заработало.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую